# How to protect second field on screen based on value in first field AS400

Tags: ibm-midrange, rpgle

I m having a screen values validation in RPGLE AS400. There are 10 fields in a subfile and user can enter value in these fields.there is one field where if user enter Y then 8 fields should be protected and only on other should be unprotected. And validation is without pressing Enter means as soon as value is entered it should check and display error message.

Answer (score 3):

It can't be done that way...

A 5250 terminal is a "smart" device.  It's not a dumb terminal that sends every key-press to the host.  Instead, the entire screen input/output buffer is sent back and forth.

The protected/unprotected state of a field is set before sending the buffer to the device and can't be changed till control is returned to your application via the enter key (or the F-keys)

What you can do is add the `CHECK(ER)` or `AUTO(RA)` keyword to your single character field; that acts as an "auto-enter".  As soon as a value is keyed, control will be returned to your application as if the user pressed enter.

5250 can handle basic validation without control being returned to your application via the use of the `CHECK` and `VALUES` keywords.

Manual: [DDS for Display Files](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_ibm_i_72/rzakc/rzakcmstdfval.htm)

Comment: The substance of this answer is good, but I disagree with your use of the terms "smart" and "dumb". When describing a terminal, *dumb* has nothing to do with whether one keystroke gets sent at a time or many, but rather how much processing power is available locally. You seem to be confusing "smart" with "buffered" and "dumb" with "unbuffered". You can absolutely have a smart unbuffered terminal and a dumb buffered one.

Comment: And be aware that `control will be returned to your application` means that the display may be locked until the application is able to run, process the input, return the 'Protect' attribute back to the display and invite the next input. Most often it'll probably be reasonably quick, but response time may vary depending on what else is going on in the system.

Comment: @user2338816 is technically correct....however anything less than sub-second response time with 5250 usually means something is wrong.

Comment: @Charles Agreed, though 'wrong' might simply be an index build or network delay or anything that changes data entry timing. A model 515 serving a hundred users can have a number of delays that aren't as likely for a well configured Power8 PureSystem. It's just hard to be sure if a solution applies in all environments.

Answer (score 1):

maybe add the check(er) attribute to the Y field your talking about.  Control will be returned to the program when the user types anything in the Y field.  If it doesn't work for subfiles just make a screen that looks like subfile.  with the check(er) attribute on the Y field that protects the other fields.

Answer (score 0):

Charles is right.

You can think of 5250 as HTML without the DOM or scripting capabilities on the client. It has some basic formatting capabilities, and even some basic field validation capabilities, but the terminal cannot be scripted to react to events. The only thing you can do is send a request back to the server by pressing one of the command keys (ENTER is a command key, in addition to the various function keys [F1-F24], and a few others). If you are using some more "modern" controls on your screen, you also have pushbuttons, radio buttons, and checkboxes that you can use to communicate with the server. You can also capture mouse events like right and left click or double click, and drag and drop, but these mouse events must be sent back to the server for interpretation. The command key presses, buttons, and mouse events must be sent to the server for anything to happen on the terminal as no scripting capability exists on the client side.